# npm link packages generated by KotlinJS

Tags: typescript, kotlin, gradle, npm, kotlin-multiplatform

I've created a Kotlin Multiplatform application that generates a JS and TypeScript output file, i'm trying to make use of those output files inside a TypeScript project
I'm fairly new to TypeScript as well as the whole npm ecosystem

[image]

The first package.json inside the hotel directory looks like this:

```
{
  "main": "kotlin/hotel.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.11",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.3",
    "css-loader": "3.4.2",
    "style-loader": "1.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "kotlin": "file:/home/vlad/Code/hotel-state/build/js/packages_imported/kotlin/1.4.0-M2",
    "kotlin-source-map-loader": "file:/home/vlad/Code/hotel-state/build/js/packages_imported/kotlin-source-map-loader/1.4.0-M2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "bundledDependencies": [],
  "name": "hotel",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

The second package.json inside the js directory looks like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/hotel",
    "packages/hotel-test"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "bundledDependencies": [],
  "name": "hotel",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

From the hotel directory, i've done

```
sudo npm link hotel
```

In my second project, i now add this to the `package.json` followed by an `npm install`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "hotel": "file:/usr/lib/node_modules/hotel",
    "lit-html": "^1.2.1"
  },
```

[image]

When i hit autocomplete, i can see the hotel package, but it keeps on showing a red line underneath it. When i try to use it in my other TypeScript files, it stops compiling

The typescript headers in that hotel.d.ts has a namespace

```
declare namespace hotel {
    type Nullable<T> = T | null | undefined
    namespace com.harakati.hotel {
        /* ErrorDeclaration: Class com.harakati.hotel.TH with kind: OBJECT */
    }

    namespace com.harakati.hotel {
        class Room {
            constructor(roomNumber: Nullable<number>)
            static Room_init_$Create$(roomNumber: Nullable<number>, $mask0: number, $marker: Nullable<any /*Class kotlin.js.DefaultConstructorMarker with kind: OBJECT*/>): com.harakati.hotel.Room
            roomNumber: number;
        }
    }
```

Am i doing the linking correctly?

Am i including this linked package correctly?

Is there anythin else that i might be missing?

Comment: Hi! First thing first, I've haven't started using MPP fpr JS yet, just to have mentioned it... Is there any reason you are doing multiple packages? E.g. your actually creating packages to be used in the NPM ecosystem? Or is this just JS that is suppose to depend on in each other in a nice fashionable way? Asking this as usually you only have one package.json in the root of the project but ofc depending on how you build/distribute your application there might be cases you make separate roots.

Comment: Since Kotlin MPP doesn't yet support split output, it was easier to create a Kotlin MPP library that compiles to JS and then pull in that generated library into external projects written in TypeScript. See my workaround below, after doing that it just works and imports become `import Booking = com.blah.Booking` instead of namespace.package.class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the generated TypeScript headers in Kotlin 1.4 M2 aren't being exported and somebody has already logged a bug for it

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37883

A quick and dirty workaround i wrote is to run some Kotlin script at the end of a Gradle build to post-process the generated TypeScript.

Include this inside the Kotlin block in your `build.gradle.kts` and the generated TS headers will import without problems in the TS project.

```
    gradle.buildFinished {
        println("==============================================================")
        val path = "$buildDir/js/packages/${project.name}/kotlin/${project.name}.d.ts"
        println("Making some adjustments to \n$path")
        val newLines = mutableListOf<String>()
        println("==============================================================")
        if (File(path).exists()) {
            File(path).readLines().forEach { line ->
                if (line.startsWith("declare namespace") || line.startsWith("}")) {
                    "// $line".let {
                        newLines.add(it)
                        println(it)
                    }
                } else if (line.trim().startsWith("namespace")) {
                    line.replace("namespace", "export namespace").let {
                        newLines.add(it)
                        println(it)
                    }
                } else {
                    line.let {
                        newLines.add(it)
                        println(it)
                    }
                }
            }
            File(path).writeText(newLines.joinToString("\n"))
        } else {
            println("$path does not exist")
        }
        println("==============================================================")
    }
```

Inside `package.json` in your TypeScript project, include it becomes straight forward

```
  "dependencies": {
    "hotel": "/home/vlad/Code/.../hotel/build/js",
    "lit-html": "^1.2.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  },
```

or simply use `npm link` to create a simlink to the generated output which then allows you to point to point to the link instead of the absolute path which could change if you move stuff around.